# C# Excel.Application - Issue with text field converted to Scientific notation

Tags: c#-4.0

I have follwing C# code which opens that tab delimited .txt file and does the saveas to Excel file. Problem what I am running into is some of the text field has value such as "9101010521297461515213" is getting converted to "9.10101E+21". How do I prevent getting converted to scientific notation and leave as text instead using below function ?

```
public void SaveTextFileAsExcel(string filefrompath, string filetopath, string newtabname)
{
    // Excel object references.
    Excel.Application m_objExcel = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbooks m_objBooks = (Excel.Workbooks)m_objExcel.Workbooks;
    Excel._Workbook m_objBook = null;
    Excel.Sheets m_objSheets = null;
    Excel._Worksheet m_objSheet = null;
    // Frequenty-used variable for optional arguments.
    object m_objOpt = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    if (filefrompath != "")
    {
        m_objBooks.OpenText(filefrompath, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows,1,
                     Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited, Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote,
                     false, true, false, false, false, false,m_objOpt, m_objOpt,
                     m_objOpt, m_objOpt, m_objOpt, m_objOpt, m_objOpt);


        m_objBook = m_objExcel.ActiveWorkbook;
        m_objSheets = m_objBook.Worksheets;

        m_objSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)m_objSheets.get_Item(1);//Get the reference of second worksheet

        string strWorksheetName = m_objSheet.Name;//Get the name of worksheet.
        if (newtabname != "") 
        { 
            m_objSheet.Name = newtabname; 
        }

        if (filetopath !="")
        {
            // Save the text file in the typical workbook format and quit Excel.
            m_objBook.SaveAs(filetopath, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
                m_objOpt, m_objOpt, m_objOpt, m_objOpt, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, m_objOpt, m_objOpt,
                m_objOpt, m_objOpt, m_objOpt);
        } //if (filetopath !="")
    } //if (filefrompath != "")

    m_objBook.Close(false, m_objOpt, m_objOpt);
    m_objExcel.Quit();
} //SaveAsExcel
```

Comment: anyone can help me with this question please ???

Comment: i got similar problem also :( even tried scinefic converter methods not returns correct data..

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is old, this is a recurrent issue in all Excel versions.

In Excel, the presentation value property is called Value but you still can access the original value using FormulaR1C1.

I have had success converting one to another by forcing Value property to be the same as FormulaR1C1 (note: you have to set the column to text) with a for loop similar to this:

```
Sub RevertFormat()
  Dim ymax, xmax, x, y
  ymax = 245
  x = 3
  For y = 2 To ymax
      Sheet1.Cells(y, x).Value = Sheet1.Cells(y, x).FormulaR1C1
  Next
End Sub
```

You should be able to access the same properties through C#, though it might be troublesome it will work.
Unfortunately I don't known a way to deactivate scientific formatting by default on Excel.